# how to do looping in XSLT?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xslt

I've got the following XML structure :

```
    <Article>
         <id>1</id>
         <line>L11</line>
         <line>L12</line>
         <line>L13</line>
     </Article>
    <Article>
         <id>2</id>
         <line>L21</line>
         <line>L22</line>
         <line>L23</line>
     </Article>
```

I want to use XSLT to iterate over all the lines of only one article at a time so that I can achieve the following structure : (every article is converted into an order, and its lines are converted to line structures in the new structure)

```
        <orders>
           <order>
              <id>1</id>
              <order_line>L11</order_line>
              <order_line>L12</order_line>
              <order_line>L13</order_line>
            </order>
           <order>
              <id>2</id>
              <order_line>L21</order_line>
              <order_line>L22</order_line>
              <order_line>L23</order_line>
            </order>
        </orders>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, short and easy solution that is based on the most fundamental and powerful XSLT design pattern: using and overriding the identity rule/template. A detailed explanation is also provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With XSLT, try to think of the task at hand as a set of patterns or rules you have to match, and the actions to be taken each time such a pattern is encountered. You can usually let the runtime worry about looping, etc, to discover patterns.

In your specific case, you've described two patterns you want special logic. Every time there is the element `Article`, you wish to apply the rule to change its name to `order`.
Every time the element `line` is encountered as a child of `Article`, replace it with `order_line`. For any other pattern, you just want to copy the contents as they were in the original document:

```
<!-- Match element Article, and whenever it's encountered, insert an 'order' element, and copy the contents of Article -->
<xsl:template match="Article">
  <order> <xsl:apply-templates/> </order>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Match element 'line', and whenever it's encountered, insert an 'order_line' element, and copy the contents -->
<xsl:template match="Article/line">
  <order_line> <xsl:apply-templates/> </order_line>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Match any other element we haven't specified explicity, and copy it verbatim -->
<xsl:template match="node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Very close! `<xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>` is the same as `<xsl:apply-templates/>`. Also, do not apply templates to attribute nodes unless you declare a rule for attributes.

Comment: @Alejandro, thanks for the catch. I adapted this from some of my own scripts which do use attributes. I cut them out to simplify, looks like I didn't cut out enough!

Answer (score 3):

This is a straightforward transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <orders>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </orders>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Article">
        <order>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </order>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="line">
        <order_line>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </order_line>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="id">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**EDIT**: A general root element rule.

Answer (score 2):

**This complete XSLT 1.0 transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <orders>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </orders>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Article">
  <order>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </order>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="line">
  <order_line>
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </order_line>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (wrapped into a single top element to make it well-formed):

```
<t>
    <Article>
        <id>1</id>
        <line>L11</line>
        <line>L12</line>
        <line>L13</line>
    </Article>
    <Article>
        <id>2</id>
        <line>L21</line>
        <line>L22</line>
        <line>L23</line>
    </Article>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<orders>
   <order>
      <id>1</id>
      <order_line>L11</order_line>
      <order_line>L12</order_line>
      <order_line>L13</order_line>
   </order>
   <order>
      <id>2</id>
      <order_line>L21</order_line>
      <order_line>L22</order_line>
      <order_line>L23</order_line>
   </order>
</orders>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule copies every node "as-is".
2. The identity rule is overriden by three templates, each of which matches a particular kind of element (the top element, `Article` and `line`) and simply renames the element, respectively to: `orders`, `order` and `order_line`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just of the top of my head but I think you can do it this way:

```
<orders>
<xsl:for-each select="//Article">
  <order>
   <id><xsl:value-of select="./id"/></id>
   <xsl:for-each select="./line">
     <order_line><xsl:value-of select="child::text()" /></order_line>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </order>
</xsl:for-each>
</orders>
```

Anyway, it should be enough to get you started. There is only a for-each loop in XSLT though, no for loop with a counter.

Comment: `./` isn't a valid XPath/XSLT expression.

Comment: Really? I seem to recall using it with success. But my memory can deceive me, anyway, I changed it to something that I think has the same effect. This was very much of the top of my head.

Comment: As minor, starting `./` or `child::` is not needed.

Comment: The first thing you should ask yourself, for just about every XSLT problem, should always be, "can I accomplish this by using the identity transform?"  The answer's "yes" a remarkable percentage of the time, and starting with the identity transform puts you in the position of working with XSLT's weird nature rather than against it.

Answer (score 0):

Your source XML file is not well-formed.  For clarity, my response assumes you've wrapped it in a  element.  This is a pretty trivial XML transformation so I've included some comments explaining what each line of code is doing.

```
<!-- change the template match xpath to whatever the root xpath is in your document -->
<xsl:template match="root">
    <orders>
        <!-- loop over each Article -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Article">
            <order>
                <!-- pass id through -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="id"/>
                <!-- loop over each line -->
                <xsl:for-each select="line">
                    <!-- create an <order_line> node -->
                    <order_line>
                        <!-- get the value of the current <line> -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </order_line>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </order>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </orders>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Using for-each loops like this is the hard way to do it.  Specify a template for each element and act accordingly, like @Eugene Talagrand

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do "looping" in XSLT is to let the XSLT processor walk the document tree for you. Anything else is fighting against the nature of XSLT.

Here's a (near-) complete solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <orders><xsl:apply-templates/></orders>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Article">
        <order>
            <id><xsl:value-of select="id"/></id>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="line"/>
        </order>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Article/line">
        <order_line><xsl:value-of select="."/></order_line>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If my internal XSLT parser is correct this would put the `<order_line>` after you closed the `<order>` tag, which is not what he wanted. Besides that it is a very good solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, but I am not a xslt expert :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="/" name="A">
    <orders>
        <xsl:for-each select="Articles/Article">
            <order>
                <id>
                    <xsl:value-of select="id" />
                </id>
                <xsl:for-each select="line">
                    <order_line>
                        <xsl:value-of select="node()"></xsl:value-of>
                    </order_line>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </order>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </orders>
</xsl:template>
```